# Get value from msg.payload return from a mysql query Node-RED

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-red

i am starting with using Node-RED. i have no JS experience.

in 1 node for the mysql DB i have to query with msg.topic.

the return msg looks like this.

```
{ "topic": "SELECT sum FROM log WHERE id = 2", "payload": [ { "sum": 15 } ], "_msgid": "c93094ee.36cf68" }
```

How do i extract the number 15 in the example out msg.payload?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in  function node following the query.

```
var sum  = msg.payload[0].sum;
...
```

the `[]` in the payload signify and array of answers so the `[0]` says take the first element from the array.

Comment: I wish it was that simple but Thank you.

Comment: According to the debug output the object and array returned as a string not as an object / array. Since your answer would be the correct in the case of an object / string and the problem was my mistake i will mark your answer as correct. thank you.